# Uploading a Folder to Azure Blob using Python

Tags: python, azure, blob

I have a requirement where I have to upload the entire folder or directory with around 70 files to the blob and not the files, using Python. the entire folder, say 'sample' is a directory with 70 files and I need to upload the 'sample' as a folder to the container. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 3):

After some searching I found out how to do it:

We have to mention the 'sample' directory as below to create or upload the folder as a whole.

```
for file in filesToUploadList:
    print(file)
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, 'sample\\'+file,outputBlobDir+'\\'+file)
```